# Trabalhando em Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

Como faço para deixar um item em negrito? print ('Empresa Soon Young Viana')
como faço para inserir uma planilha de imposto de renda? print ('PRODUTO''\t'u'PREÇO UNITÁRIO''\t''QUANTIDADE''\t'u'PREÇO TOTAL''\t''ICMS')

Answer (score 0):

Instale o TermColor:
[TermColor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor)

```
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint

    text = colored('Hello, World!', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])
    print(text)
    cprint('Hello, World!', 'green', 'on_red')

    print_red_on_cyan = lambda x: cprint(x, 'red', 'on_cyan')
    print_red_on_cyan('Hello, World!')
    print_red_on_cyan('Hello, Universe!')

    for i in range(10):
        cprint(i, 'magenta', end=' ')



    cprint("Attention!", 'red', attrs=['bold'], file=sys.stderr)
```

deve funcionar

Comment: Olá. Este jeito  não está funcionando, eu já tentei. aparece o seguinte:

Comment: [1mHello World ![0m

Comment: Comigo também não funcionou (Windows 7)... Essa solução não seria restrita a ambientes POSIX?

Comment: editei a resposta